# Google Cloud: split request

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to put something in front of my apps and Cloud Compute in Google Cloud, in a way that when a HTTP request comes in for any app URL's I can send another request to another APP somewhere and then move on with the original request of the user.

What is the tool in Google Cloud to achieve that?

Comment: Do you want a request duplication (mirroring)? Or do you want to trigger an event when a request comes in? Can you be more precise in your expectation?

Comment: Hi, it would be like an event!

Comment: You can't create an event on incoming request. however, by thinking to your use case, Traffic mirroring can do the job: Mirror the traffic to another service, that perform "something" when a new request comes in. -> That's your event